# Combining 3 seperate Onedit functions in google script/Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to solve a problem that I have been working on last 2-3 hours which I think for many would be quite easy. I got the following function which works great although sometimes a little slow.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Team' || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'D16') return; 
  e.range.offset(0, 0).getValue() === 'Show' ? sheet.showRows(17, 7) : sheet.hideRows(17, 7)
```

I however got 2 the almost identical functions i need running at the same time. Namely

no.2

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Team' || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'D25') return; 
  e.range.offset(0, 0).getValue() === 'Show' ? sheet.showRows(26, 10) : sheet.hideRows(26, 10)
}
```

No3.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Team' || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'D37') return; 
  e.range.offset(0, 0).getValue() === 'Show' ? sheet.showRows(38, 10) : sheet.hideRows(38, 10)
}
```

What I tried to get all 3 working seperately:

1. Simply Adding all 3
2. Adding all 3 with different function name
3. adding multiple ifs within the same code(function) (not sure if it was done correctly though as it did not work)

Comment: Regarding number 3, please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also 'merge' the three scripts into one. Try something like this

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet, cells, rows, ind;
sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
cells = ['D16', 'D25', 'D37'];
rows = [[17, 7], [26, 10], [38, 10]];
ind = cells.indexOf(e.range.getA1Notation());
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Team' || ind == -1) return;
e.value === 'Show' ? sheet.showRows(rows[ind][0], rows[ind][1]) : sheet.hideRows(rows[ind][0], rows[ind][1])
}
```

and see if that works ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1 and 2

> 1. Simply Adding all 3

This doesn't work because the functions use the same name. Only the last one will be ran.

> 2. Adding all 3 with different function name
>      This could work, but to be triggered by a simple on edit trigger, they need be called by function named onEdit(e). Example

```
function onEdit(e){
  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();
  myFunction3();
}
```

Comment: I will also note that if you do not care which function runs first, you can add 3 installable triggers that are all triggered by `onEdit`. Otherwise this answer is the easiest to implement with what you already have. It also seems that you always have the same `!== 'Team'` but the only difference is the active cell. You might want to just use a `switch`, which you can read up on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)